# How can I refer to a field from a table which is not related with the field directly?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, foreign-keys

In Django ORM I tried to JOIN 4 tables, Order, OrderDetail, Item and ItemPhoto and to access ItemPhoto.photo from Order table.

At first, I wrote code with Subquery starting with OrderDetail table and could get fields I wanted to get, but I realized the result was not what I expected.

Then, I changed my codes and tried to use Subquery starting from Order table, but I noticed Order table didn't have item field and it seemed to be difficult to use Subquery in Django in this case.

So, I wrote code without Subquery and managed to reach ItemPhoto.photo, but it is complecated and difficult to use in Template to some extent.

How can I make my code better to refer to a field from a table which is not related with the field directly?

```
queryset = Order.objects.prefetch_related( 
    Prefetch(
        'orderdetail_orderid', 
        queryset=OrderDetail.objects.select_related('order', 'item'),
        to_attr='oor',
    ),
).filter(user=user).order_by('-order')

# I could access to ItemPhoto.photo, but it's complicated.
[p.photo for q in queryset for i in q.orderdetail_orderid.all() for p in i.item.item_photo.all()]
```

models.py(omitted)

```
class ItemCategory(models.Model):
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="")
    category_type = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Item(models.Model): # Product
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, default="")
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.00, 
        blank=False,
    ) 
    category = models.ForeignKey(ItemCategory, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
        related_name="item_category")

class ItemPhoto(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="item_photo",)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, 
        upload_to=get_itemimage_path)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True, 
        related_name="order_user",
    )
    total_price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.00, 
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        related_name="orderdetail_orderid",) 
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True, 
        related_name="orderdetail_item",)
# price
# quantity
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Python: 3.9 / Django: 4.1 / MySQL / SQLite3

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I might not understand what you wrote perfectly, but I delete my codes and changed my question. Is it ok?

Comment: "Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question." There are still 3 question marks in a row. Ask 1 question. What is your question? Again: Either ask about 1 minimal piece of code that doesn't do what you expect, or ask about how you are stuck while you give relevant working code parts & explain how your code parts are relevant & give no bad code & no stories about bad code.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Thanks. You edited my question, so I thought it was proper. But isn't it too strict??? I wonder that people think this guy post the question without struggling and tackling if I just post simple question and code. That is why I wrote several codes. However, if my way viorated StackOverFlow's rule and concept, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to come up with a different approach with using Subquery.

```
subqs = ItemPhoto.objects.filter(item=OuterRef('item')).filter(priority=1)

queryset = Order.objects.prefetch_related( 
    Prefetch(
        'orderdetail_orderid',
        queryset=OrderDetail.objects.select_related('order', 'item').annotate(
            item_photos=Subquery(subqs.values('photo')),
        ),
        to_attr='oor',
    ),
).filter(user=user)
prices = [o.price for q in queryset for o in q.oor]
photos = [o.item_photos for q in queryset for o in q.oor]
```

I could reach ItemPhoto.photo with Subquery easier, although I wonder if this is the best way or not.